# Лишний оператор возврата в void методе

Tags: java

Есть `void` метод, который работает при нажатии на `button`: если в `textfield` 0, то ничего не происходит, если другое число - дописывает 0.

Пишет "лишний оператор возврата". Как тогда мне поступить?

```
screenValue = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
if (screenValue == 0) {
   return;
} else {
   jTextField1.setText(String.valueOf(screenValue) + 0);
}
```

Comment: Добавьте пример всего метода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу, что появляется сообщение IDE о лишнем операторе возврата, а не компилятора. Ваш пример можно исправить следующим образом:

```
screenValue = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
if (screenValue != 0) {
    jTextField1.setText(String.valueOf(screenValue) + 0);
}
```

Либо можно еще упростить:

```
String value = jTextField1.getText();
if (!"0".equals(value)) {
    jTextField1.setText(value + "0");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, только теперь понял глупость вопроса.